# How to read Kafka Message Key from Spring cloud streams?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring cloud streams to consume a message from Kafka.

Is it possible to read the Kafka Message Key from the code?

I have a Kafka topic that generally has 2 types of messages. The action to be taken varies depending on the message key. I see the spring documentation has only the following to read the message. Here, I need to specify the actual mapping of the message (Greetings class here). However, I need a way through which I can read the message key and determine the deserializable Pojo

```java
public class GreetingsListener {

    @StreamListener(GreetingsProcessor.INPUT)
    public void handleGreetings(@Payload Greetings request) {
     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
@StreamListener(GreetingsProcessor.INPUT)
public void handleGreetings(@Payload Greetings request, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY)String  key) {

}
```

You need to provide a proper deserializer for the key. For e.g. if your key is String, then you can provide:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

If there is a need to use different key deserializer for different input channels, this setting can be extended under producer section of each kafka bindings.  For example:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          <channel_name>:
            consumer:
              startOffset: latest
              autoCommitOffset: true
              autoCommitOnError: true
              configuration:
                key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [functional programming model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function) which since Spring Cloud Stream v.4 has replaced the previous annotated-based approach:

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<String>> listen() {
    return message -> {
        Object key = message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_KEY);
        System.out.println("Message " + message.getPayload() + " has the " + key + " key");
    };
}
```

This code is based on the [example in Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_partitioning_with_the_kafka_binder).